# How to change the master username at git in WebStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

WebStorm tries to push my project to an account that does not exist anymore. How do I change it? I have already added the new account to WebStorm and it still tries pushing to the old account.

[image: the explaining]

Answer (score 1):

The entry highlighted on the screenshot is the commit author. This information is written in the commit, and is not related to the account that is used to push the change.
Author is determined by git configuration. You can check and change it using CLI - `git config user.name` and `git config user.email`

To change the author of the commit in question you need to re-do the commit.
Make sure git user is correctly set in git config, then undo the commit, and commit changes again.

To push, WebStorm will authenticate using the account configured in Settings | Version Control | GitHub, or according to the ssh config if ssh access is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in Settings>Repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Setting>General>Repository name>rename